# Plex media servers appears offline

Tags: networking, plex

I have set up a plex media server, after struggling with permissions, my files finally show up in the plex web app. The server is listed on my phone and ipad, but it appears offline.

I'm new to Linux, but this is what I've tried:
Restarting the service
Logging in and out again
Reinstalling plex

To be complete, my ipad and phone are on the same network as the server. And plex used to work when my pc still ran on Windows.

Edit: I'm on ubuntu 18.04.4. Ubuntu desktop

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Plex works great on Ubuntu. Are you saying that connecting to Plex works properly on your Web Browser, but fails to connect (seems offline) when connecting using the Plex app?

Comment: Yes that’s right. It is listed in the app, but it appears offline.

Comment: Try connecting, using your Web Browser, to the http://plex.tv URL instead of whatever you are using right now. Do you get the same failure to connect (seems offline) after you login?

Comment: Thanks, it works now.